# Eclipse Gradle project: JAXB doesn't create java classes from nested WSDL file

Tags: java, gradle, jaxb, wsdl, xjc

I have 2 .wsdl files and 4 .xsd files. `wsdl1` imports `wsdl2` and `wsdl2` imports all 4 xsd files.
I have a Gradle project in Eclipse Neon and want to use

```
task genJaxb {
    ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb"
    ext.classesDir = "${buildDir}/classes/jaxb"
    ext.schema = "src/main/resources/wsdl1.wsdl"

    outputs.dir classesDir

    doLast() {
        project.ant {
            taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
            mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)
            mkdir(dir: classesDir)

            xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema) {
                arg(value: "-wsdl")
                produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
            }

            javac(destdir: classesDir, source: 1.6, target: 1.6, debug: true,
                    debugLevel: "lines,vars,source",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath) {
                src(path: sourcesDir)
                include(name: "**/*.java")
                include(name: "*.java")
            }

            copy(todir: classesDir) {
                fileset(dir: sourcesDir, erroronmissingdir: false) {
                    exclude(name: "**/*.java")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to generate java classes from the wsdl file. It doesn't work but Gradle shows the jaxb task as green. If i instead do `ext.schema = "src/main/resources/wsdl2.wsdl"` it generates the classes successfully, but I'm missing the content from `wsdl1`.

Edit after answer:

```
task generateJava {
    inputs.file = "src/main/resources/wsdl1.wsdl"
    outputs.dir = "${buildDir}/generated/java"
    doLast {
        project.ant {
            taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
            mkdir" ${buildDir}/generated/java"

            xjc(destdir: file(${buildDir}/generated/java).absolutePath, schema: inputs) {
                arg(value: "-wsdl")
                produces(dir: outputs, includes: "**/*.java")
            }
        }
    }
} 
sourceSets.main.java {
    srcDir "{$buildDir}/generated/java"
}
compileJava.dependsOn generateJava
```

Throwing following error: `No such property: file for class: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs Possible solutions: files`

Answer (score 0):

You're not quite thinking in the Gradle way. Here's what you should do:

1. Generate your java files in a directory under $buildDir so it's cleaned via the "clean" task (never generate in src/main/java)
2. Add the generated directory to the "main" SourceSet (so it's compiled by the compileJava task in the "java" plugin)
3. Make the "compileJava" task depend on your task
4. Be sure to configure the task inputs/outputs on your task to support UP-TO-DATE skipping

Eg:

```
apply plugin: 'java' 
task generateJava {
    inputs.file 'src/main/resources/mywsdl.wsdl'
    outputs.dir "$buildDir/generated/java"
    doLast {
        mkdir "$buildDir/generated/java"
        ant {
           taskdef(name: 'xjc', ...)
           xjc(destdir: "$buildDir/generated/java", ...) {
             ... 
           } 
        } 
    }
} 
sourceSets.main.java {
    srcDir "$buildDir/generated/java"
}
compileJava.dependsOn generateJava
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Sadly I don't really know how to edit my build.gradle file in response to your answer. I suppose I need to get rid of the genJaxb task, but I don't know what to put inside of the doLast{} of the generateJava task.

Comment: I've updated the solution (you'll need to fill in the "...")

Comment: Thank you again, but I'm getting an error on your third line: `No such property: file for class: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs
Possible solutions: files`
I couldn't find a solution on Google or on my own, maybe you can help. I'll update the question with my updated setup.

Comment: I think you've done `inputs.file = 'foo'` instead of `inputs.file 'foo' `

Comment: You were right about my mistake. But in line 9 it didn't work with `file("..")` because nested text is apparently not allowed. If I exchange `file("$buildDir/generated/java").absolutePath` for either the absolute path or `outputs` I receive a NullPointerexeption. I don't really know how to proceed and feel like I've tried everything.

Comment: Changed to `xjc(destdir: "$buildDir/generated/java", ...)`

Comment: I appreciate your extended help, but I was receiving a NPE. I managed to solve it by not using the variables `outputs` and `inputs` but rather the paths. It no longer fails the generateJava task, but now it is not generating any classes. If i put `wsdl2` it is also not generating classes, only the packages but only for 3 of the 4 schemas. Do you have any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Huh? inputs & outputs is configuring the task inputs & outputs for up to date checks these are not the problem

Comment: I don't know, I changed it to `xjc(destdir: "$buildDir/generated/java", schema: "C:/.../src/main/resources/wsdls/wsdl1.wsdl")` from `xjc(destdir: "$buildDir/generated/java", schema: inputs)` and the NPE was gone. So now the Gradle task is no longer failing, but the java folder under `Project and External Dependencies` was empty.

Answer (score 0):

I ran through the exact same problem. Thanks to this tutorial it worked! https://jaxenter.com/tutorial-gradle-soap-features-revealed-104493.html

In short, instead of using the xjc plugin to create java classes, I used wsimport which worked like a charm.

```
configurations {
    jaxws
}

task genWs {
    ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb"
    ext.classesDir = "${buildDir}/classes/jaxb"
    ext.schema = ""//source to your wsdl file here

    outputs.dir classesDir

    doLast() {
        project.ant {
            taskdef (name:'wsimport',
                classname:'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport',
                classpath:configurations.jaxws.asPath)
            mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)
            mkdir(dir: classesDir)

            wsimport(keep:true,
                destdir: classesDir,
                sourcedestdir: sourcesDir,
                wsdl: schema)
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    jaxws 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.1.4'
}

compileJava {
    dependsOn genWs
}
```